# In matplotlib, plotting the histogram using plot and the returns of hist

Tags: python, matplotlib

In order to test the returns of hist, I want to use them using plot via matplotlib. hist give the following returns:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
counts, bins, bars = plt.hist(x)
```

where x is the vector of data you want to plot the histogram.

I have tried the following syntax

```
plt.plot(bins,counts)
```

I get the following error

```
Error: x and y must have the same first dimension, but have shapes (501,) and (500,)
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can try `plt.plot(bins[:-1],counts)` `bins` variable contains bin edges, so it is `len(counts) + 1`

Comment: Thanks you for answer, it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the matplotlib documentationof [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

> bins : array 
>    The edges of the bins. Length nbins + 1 (nbins left edges
>   and right edge of last bin). Always a single array even when multiple
>   data sets are passed in.

So the returned value `bins` is the number of bins + 1 because it includes the left bin edges and right edge of the last bin.

You might not want to include the right edge of the last bin, therefore you can slice the array:

```
plt.plot(bins[:-1], counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

This is the simplest one I guess.